# Parsing datastore Entity in Python efficiently

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

So right now, datastore `ds.query(kind='users')` returns me a response in the form:

```
<Entity(u'users', 5633378543992832L) {u'username': u'xyz', u'user_ip': '127.0.0.1', u'name': u'xyz', u'password': 'something', u'register_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 8, 5, 50, 1, 443212, tzinfo=<UTC>)}>
```

And although I can iterate it like this:

```
result = {}
for oneItem in query.fetch():
    # oneItem is Entity iterable as shown above
    for oneProp in oneItem:
        result[oneProp] = oneItem[oneProp]
```

And access any property by `something = result['password']`

Which works fine but it is grossly inefficient. Is there any way I can directly access any specific property without using for loops or another data structure? Similar to accessing a value in JSON.

I am using `from google.cloud import datastore`

Comment: What are you trying to illustrate in your example? Your for-loop keeps overwriting the values in `result` with the next entity. You are effectively just doing this: `result = query.fetch()[-1]`

Comment: ahh yes, in my case it would only ever have one entity which again I can't, or don't know, how to access directly.

query.fetch() doesn't support indexing. I wouldn't be posting this question if it did.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd be retrieving the desired object by key, instead of loading up the whole table.

It's a little challenging to give you exact code since I can't tell which library you are using to access the datastore. I've always used `ndb` but it seems like you are using this one:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/index.html

To fetch by key you'd do:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud.datastore.key import Key
ds = datastore.Client()
oneItem = ds.get(Key(u'users', 5633378543992832L, project=project))
```

and then at this point, just interact with it `oneItem['password']`

The id `5633378543992832L` should be supplied to you from the current session. So you'd only need to query during session creation. Something like this:

```
def create_session(username, raw_password):
    client = datastore.Client()
    query = client.query(kind=u'users')
    query.add_filter('username', '=', username)
    query.add_filter('password', '=', _your_password_hash_function(raw_password))
    results = query.fetch(1)
    if results:
        return _create_session_for_user(results[0])
    raise Exception("Invalid username/password")
```

You'll need add an index for the above query to work. It seems like your not using app engine, so you probably have to add indices through the web console

Comment: Thanks. It worked...locally. But turns out GAE only supports ndb in the standard env which seems better among the two anyway.